# Calling a stored procedure for a column during select

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, birt

I have a stored procedure named "OUTPUT_DATE" that takes in a date, and then outputs the date in the standardized format specified in another section of the database.

I am currently working on creating a BIRT report using this, however would like to call this stored procedure while getting the data to format a specific column of data. My question is, is it possible to call a stored procedure on my select statement, or is there another method to do this using BIRT?

I am already aware of the functions build into BIRT to output specific date formats, but this does not currently work the way I want since our date format is specified in the database.

My preference would be something similar to this...

```
SELECT col1, col2, OUTPUT_DATE(dateCol) FROM the_table
```

Comment: You can't call a procedure like that. Does it really need to be a procedure? An inline table valued function is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can do this with a function, not a procedure

Comment: Is there a reason that this logic is implemented in a stored procedure rather than a function?  And are you using Oracle or SQL Server?  How does your Oracle procedure "output the date"?  An `out` parameter?

Comment: To answer - yes, it is an out parameter. I was wondering if it was possible using a stored procedure but it looks like function might end up being the way to go.

Comment: You should output the date as a date and if you need a specific date format, it should be handled in the GUI

Comment: @JamesZ although I personally agree with you - the system is already in place on a large project, and it spans multiple countries with (sometimes sadly) difference formats. Either way, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you should create a user defined function (scalar valued) instead of your stored procedure - functions can be called the way you want to.

Document & sample from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=sql.105).aspx)